# fill two drop-down-list in one view with two models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two drop-down-list in my partial view.
I wanna fill them . of course from diffrent tables.
So I must  use two different models  in my view.
I  did it by viewbag .
like below :

My class:

```
         public class HelperClass

        {

       public static List<tbl_TypeOfSend> GetTypSend()
        { 
        using(var db=new ProjectContext())
        {
            var Lst = db. tbl_TypeOfSend.ToList();
            return Lst;
        }


    }
    public static List<tbl_TypOfPaye> GetTypPay()
    {
        using (var db = new ProjectContext())
        {
            var Lst = db. tbl_TypOfPaye.ToList();
            return 
        }
        }



        }
```

My controller:

```
       public ActionResult MyAction()
        {
        ViewBag. TypSend = HelperClass.GetTypSend ();
        ViewBag. GetTypPay = HelperClass.GetTypPay ();
        return PartialView();
        }
```

In view:
i want some thing like below .i know it dose not work.how can do it.

```
              @model List<Project.Models. tbl_TypeOfSend >

                        <select  id="id" class="span5">
                            <option>select type send</option>
                           @foreach (var item in ViewBag.TypSend)
                            {

                            <option  value="@item.id"> @item.TypesendField </option>
                            }

                        </select>
                     .
                     .
                     .
                     .


                      @model List<Project.Models. tbl_TypOfPaye >
                        <select class="span5">
                           <option>--- select type payment ---</option>
                             @foreach (var item in ViewBag. GetTypPay)
                            {

                            <option value="@item.id">@item.TypePaymentField</option>
                             }
                        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

just change this line

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.TypSend as List<tbl_TypeOfSend>)

@foreach (var item in ViewBag.GetTypPay as List<tbl_TypOfPaye>)
```

and it will work!

PS: by the way i don't like the way you fetch data from database, i think it's better to get data in one call

Comment: thanks . but why it dose not show any things in my drop-down . i use break point and all things is true .i use HelperClass.GetTypSend (). count() , and it fills. but dosen't show